# How to randomize an object: Map<Author, List<Book>> with EasyRandom in Java?

Tags: java, dictionary, random, randomized-algorithm

I'm trying to randomize an object: Map<Author, List> with easyRandom for testing.

For the moment I haven't get my code to compile. So my code is something like:

```
MapRandomizer<Author, List<Book>> mapRandomizer = new MapRandomizer<>(Author.class, ArrayList<Book>.class);
        Map<Author, List<Book>> map = mapRandomizer.getRandomValue();
```

But I don't know how to put the list (ArrayList.class???) as a parameter of the mapRandomizer.

Does anyone knows how to get my code to compile and create a random object of type:  Map<Author, List>?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

You can't really create a random map without creating random entries. You'll need to be able to create each contained type (in your example `Author` and `Book`) randomly. Putting them in a list and map is just creating the proper containers then.

So what you really probably have is

```
class MapRandomizer<K, List<E>> {
 private ItemRandomizer<K> keyRandomizer;
 private ListRandomizer<E> listRandomizer;

 public Map<K, List<E>> createMap() {
  // random count, for each entry create random K and random List<E>
  // using keyRandomizer and listRandomizer
 }
}
```

with

```
class ListRandomizer<E> {
 private ItemRandomizer<E> entryRandomizer;

 public List<E> createList() {
  // random count, fill list with that amount of entries 
  // using the entry randomizer
 }
}
```

and then you can create your concrete randomizer with

```
MapRandomizer<Author, List<Book>> randomizer = new MapRandomizer<>(
 new AuthorRandomizer(), new ListRandomizer<Book>(new BookRandomizer())
);
```

In this, `AuthorRandomizer` and `BookRandomizer` will need to implement `ItemRandomizer<Author>` and `ItemRAndomizer<Book>`, respectively.

EDIT:
since you posted your code in the reply, you should be easily able to wrap `generate(Autor.class)` to `implement ItemRandomizer<Author>`.

Answer (score 0):

Right now I'm trying to do it the long way:

```
    Author author1 = generator.nextObject(Author.class);
    Author author2 = generator.nextObject(Author.class);
    Author author3 = generator.nextObject(Author.class);
    
    List< Book> bookList1= generator.objects(Book.class, 3).collect(Collectors.toList());
    List< Book> bookList2= generator.objects(Book.class, 2).collect(Collectors.toList());
    List< Book> bookList3= generator.objects(Book.class, 4).collect(Collectors.toList());
    
    Map< Author, List< Book>> map= new HashMap<>();
    map.put(author1 , bookList1);
    map.put(author2 , bookList2);
    map.put(author3 , bookList3);
```

Comment: Pardon me, but it's not clear. Are you [answering your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) or should this code be part of your question?

Comment: @Abra This was the solution I found to my problem, but I wanted a general/better solution solution.